# Не работает onclick

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте! Пользователь переключает радио-кнопки и квадрат изменяет цвет. Вот два файла. Первый файл работает. Во втором файле, я убрал событие onclick из html разметки и решил его вставить с помощью javascript. Не работает. В чем я ошибся?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>New Page</title>
 <style>
  * {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
  }
  .one {
   height: 400px;
   width: 600px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   margin-top: -200px;
   margin-left: -300px;
   border: 1px solid;
  }
  .l {
   height: 400px;
   width: 199px;
   float: left;
   border-right: 1px solid;
  }
  .r {
   height: 400px;
   width: 400px;
   float: left;
  }
  .l-center {
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   position: relative;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   margin-top: -50px;
   margin-left: -50px;
   font-size: 24px;
  }
  .r-center {
   height: 200px;
   width: 200px;
   position: relative;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   margin-top: -100px;
   margin-left: -100px;
   background-color: #F00;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="one">
  <div class="l">
   <div class="l-center">
    <form>
     <input id="r0" type="radio" name="color" value="red" checked="checked" onclick="funColor()" />
     &nbsp;
     <label>red</label>
     <br />
     <input id="r1" type="radio" name="color" value="green" onclick="funColor()" />
     &nbsp;
     <label>green</label>
     <br />
     <input id="r2" type="radio" name="color" value="blue" onclick="funColor()" />
     &nbsp;
     <label>blue</label>
     <br />
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="r">
   <div id="div1" class="r-center"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
<script>
 function funColor() {
  var color;
  var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
   if(elements[i].type=='radio' && elements[i].name=='color' && elements[i].checked) {
    color = elements[i].value;
   }
  }
  if(color=='red') {
   document.getElementById('div1').style.backgroundColor="#F00";
  }
  else if(color=='green') {
   document.getElementById('div1').style.backgroundColor="#0F0";
  }
  else if(color=='blue') {
   document.getElementById('div1').style.backgroundColor="#00F";
  }
 }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Второй файл

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>New Page</title>
 <style>
  * {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
  }

  .one {
   height: 400px;
   width: 600px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   margin-top: -200px;
   margin-left: -300px;
   border: 1px solid;
  }

  .l {
   height: 400px;
   width: 199px;
   float: left;
   border-right: 1px solid;
  }

  .r {
   height: 400px;
   width: 400px;
   float: left;
  }

  .l-center {
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   position: relative;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   margin-top: -50px;
   margin-left: -50px;
   font-size: 24px;
  }

  .r-center {
   height: 200px;
   width: 200px;
   position: relative;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   margin-top: -100px;
   margin-left: -100px;
   background-color: #F00;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="one">
  <div class="l">
   <div class="l-center">
    <form>
     <input id="r0" type="radio" name="color" value="red" checked="checked" />
     &nbsp;
     <label>red</label>
     <br />
     <input id="r1" type="radio" name="color" value="green" />
     &nbsp;
     <label>green</label>
     <br />
     <input id="r2" type="radio" name="color" value="blue" />
     &nbsp;
     <label>blue</label>
     <br />
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="r">
   <div id="div1" class="r-center"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <script>
  window.onload=function() {
   for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
    document.getElementById('r'+i).onclick=funColor();
   }
  }
  function funColor() {
   var color;
   var elements=document.getElementsByTagName('input');
   for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
    if (elements[i].type=='radio'&&elements[i].name=='color'&&elements[i].checked) {
     color=elements[i].value;
    }
   }
   if (color=='red') {
    document.getElementById('div1').style.backgroundColor="#F00";
   }
   else if (color=='green') {
    document.getElementById('div1').style.backgroundColor="#0F0";
   }
   else if (color=='blue') {
    document.getElementById('div1').style.backgroundColor="#00F";
   }
  }
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Чёрт! Оформите код, ё-моё. При написании надо было написать с энтерами, как в текстовом редакторе, когда вы работаете, потом выделить этот код и нажать вверху панели кнопку "{}". Так глаза можно сломать!

Comment: Я выделил код и нажал на кнопку "{}", но ничего не получилось. Просто скопируйте себе и сохраните с расширением .html. Там все в одном файле и css и javascript. А потом другой скопируйте.

Answer (score 1):

Вы присваиваете обработчику результат работы функции funColor (которая у вас ничего не возвращает). Чтобы присвоить функцию нужно указывать идентификатор без скобок:

```
document.getElementById('r'+i).onclick = funColor;
```

а еще лучше

```
document.getElementById('r'+i).addEventListener('click',funColor);
```

Comment: БОЛЬШОЕ СПАСИБО!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! ЗАРАБОТАЛО!!!!!!!!!!!! Но ведь в первом варианте, функция так же ничего не возвращает, но присваивается oncklic=funColor() как функция, а здесь как идентификатор, вот это не понятно...

Comment: @Anton121212, нет в первом случае вы присвоили некий код свойству onclick, который будет выполнен при клике. во втором случае код уже выполняется.  
эквивалент первого случая (грубо):

    .onclick = function(){eval("funColor()");} 

в HTML в onclick кстати сказать можно много вссякого написать, не только вызов одной функции. например:

    onclick="alert('foo');document.title='bar';funColor();return false;"

ну и так далее...

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, а что если так?

    document.getElementById('r'+i).onclick = "funColor();";
По идее в таком случае функция funColor не выполняется, и в событие onClick вписывается не результат выполнения функции, а обычный текст. Но html-ю пофиг, и при нажатии на элемент, он вызывает функцию funColor. Я ведь прав?
P.S.: я не проверял этот вариант. Просто предположение. :)

Comment: Здравствуйте Юрий! Этот вариант не работает
document.getElementById('r'+i).onclick="funColor()";

Я так думаю, что в том варианте, который Вы подсказали
document.getElementById('r'+i).onclick=funColor;

funColor является одним из вариантов объявления функции. 
//1 вариант
function fun1() {
document.write("<p>Привет Мир!</p>");
}

//2 вариант
var fun2=function() {
document.write("<p>Hello World!!</p>");
}

//3 вариант
fun3 = function () {
document.write("<p>Lugansk is a city!</p>");
}

//4 вариант
var fun4 = new Function(alert("JavaScript!"));

Другого объяснения я пока не нашел.

Comment: Вам нужно только понять разницу между скриптом и html (как в нем задаются какие атрибуты элементов и что они означают). В html объявление обработчика идет в виде текста, который будет выполнен только при срабатывании события. 
http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-script  

В javascript'е объекту (свойству объекта, переменной) вы можете присваивать все что захотите, но чтоб назначить обработчик, присвоить функцию, а не результат ее выполнения или строку или что бы то ни было другое нужно писать идентификатор функции. без скобок.

Comment: @intro94, нет, не правы. это код не в html, а в javascript'е. вы присвоили некоторому свойству строку. исполняться она не будет.  
N.B. JavaScript может исполняться не только на странице браузера, где есть HTML, но и например в [WHS](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host) или в [node.js](http://nodejs.org), где ни html, ни как следствие DOM нет и в помине.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, просто если напрямую в хтмл писать событие onClick мы же не инициализируем функцию. Мы пишем текст. Например

    <input id="r1" type="radio" name="color" value="green" onClick="funColor();" />
И работает же. Так и я думал - при загрузке страницы просто вписывать текст.

Comment: @intro94 потому-что при такой установке слушателем события является тело функции в кавычках, именно поэтому funColor при таком подходе теряет контекст. конкретно происходит нечто подобное:

element.addEventListener('click',new Function('funColor()'));

Comment: Ясно. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload=function() {
    for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
         document.getElementById('r'+i).onclick=funColor;
    }
}
```

Замените начало скрипта во втором файле на то, что я написал выше. Вы присваивали `onclick` то, что возвращала функция (в данном случае функция возвращает `undefined`), а вам надо не результат функции присвоить, а саму функцию.